# Capturar salida de un comando

Tags: perl, substring

Necesito capturar la siguiente respuesta, obviando el **título** y los **---**; además, los campos **VACIOS**, **NULL**, y **TEXTO**:

```
Slot  Type     PEC      Primary  Secondary
----  ----  ----------  -------  ---------
  1   DMC               OOS Mtce Unequipped  
  2   DMC   NTBN19CA    IS       
  3   DMC               NULL     
  4   DMC   NTBN19EA    IS       
  5   DMC   NTBN19CA    IS       
  6   DMC   NTBN19CA    IS       
  7   DMC   NTBN19CA    IS       
  8   DMC   NTBN19CA    IS       
  9   DMC   NTBN19CA    IS       
 10   DMC   NTBN19CA    IS       
 11   DMC   NTBN19CA    IS       
 12   DMC   NTBN19EA    IS       
 13   DMC   NTBN19CA    IS       
 14   DMC   NTBN19CA    IS       
 15   MSC   NTBN20BA    IS       
 --   SM    NTBN21AB    IS       
 --   SM    NULL        NULL     
 --   SM    NULL        NULL     
 --   SM    NULL        NULL
```

Mi *script* en *Perl*:

```
for my $line (split "\r", $pmatch) 
{
    $line =~ s/\s*\n$//;
    if ($line =~ /More/) {
        $t->print(''); # enter
        next PAGE;
    }
    elsif ($line =~ /^\s+[\d-]/) {
        my (undef, $slot, $type, $pec, $primary, $secondary) = split /\s+/, $line, 6;
        push @$vplevels, {
              slot      => $slot
            , type      => $type
            , pec       => $pec
            , primary   => $primary
            , secondary => $secondary
            , opc       => $opc };
    }
}

return $vplevels;
```

Tengo un `split()` de un dato que a veces viene con las *5 columnas* completas y otras veces no, por lo que el valor de **PEC** toma el de **Primary**. Sucede lo mismo en las otras columnas. Por ende, no encuentro cómo poder validar si viene vacía, que la mantenga, y los demás valores todos en sus campos correspondientes.

Comment: Por favor, no pongas imágenes de texto! Necesitamos poder copiar tus datos para ver si funcione nuestra solución. Si pones imágenes es inútil. Y tienes que mostrarnos el programa completo. Mejor dicho, en forma que se puede usar. Que es el `$pmatch`? Como puedo saber que hace tu código si no se que intenta procesar?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Supongamos que la salida del programa viene en un archivo.

Hacemos funciones que necesitamos:

1. Convertimos el archivo a texto, para esto creamos la función `archivo_hacia_texto`, en este caso elegimos el nombre `tabla_texto.txt`.

#### Contenido de *tabla_texto.txt*:

```
Slot  Type     PEC      Primary  Secondary
----  ----  ----------  -------  ---------
  1   DMC               OOS Mtce Unequipped  
  2   DMC   NTBN19CA    IS       
  3   DMC               NULL     
  4   DMC   NTBN19EA    IS       
  5   DMC   NTBN19CA    IS       
  6   DMC   NTBN19CA    IS       
  7   DMC   NTBN19CA    IS       
  8   DMC   NTBN19CA    IS       
  9   DMC   NTBN19CA    IS       
 10   DMC   NTBN19CA    IS       
 11   DMC   NTBN19CA    IS       
 12   DMC   NTBN19EA    IS       
 13   DMC   NTBN19CA    IS       
 14   DMC   NTBN19CA    IS       
 15   MSC   NTBN20BA    IS       
 --   SM    NTBN21AB    IS       
 --   SM    NULL        NULL     
 --   SM    NULL        NULL     
 --   SM    NULL        NULL
```

2. La función `capturar_posiciones`, convierte la línea de guiones a un array de posiciones.
3. La función `capturar_campos`, se va a encargar de agregar cada celda de la tabla a un array matriz, removiendo los espacios de los costados. Ejemplo: `NTBN19CA`.

   3.2. *Nota*: Debido a la complicación de programar en *Perl*, solo será un array de una dimensión y no una matriz de dos dimensiones.
4. La función `unificar_pendientes`, lo que hará es combinar todas líneas que estén antes de la línea de guiones.

   4.2. En este caso, se considera verticalmente la combinación de celdas:

   - La primera columna será en la celda `cabe_segu`
   - La segunda columna será `cera_nda`.
   - La tercera columna será `primera_cabecera`.

     ```
     +----+----+--------+
     |cabe|cera|primera |
     +----+----+--------+
     |segu|nda |cabecera|
     +----+----+--------+
     ```
5. La función `obtener_matriz_campos` lo que hace es agregar cada celda al array. Para esto, se parte el texto en líneas, y desde ahí, en cada línea se usa `capturar_campos` y `capturar_posiciones` para obtener cada celda. Al final se usa `unificar_pendientes` para agregar las celdas de las cabeceras al final del array.

   5.2 *Nota:* El primer elemento del array se agrega un valor que representa la cantidad de columnas.
6. La función `leer_matriz`, lee el array devuelto por `obtener_matriz_campos` y muestra en consola el resultado de capturar la matriz.

Lo siguiente es la línea de guiones:

```
----  ----  ----------  -------  ---------
```

Miramos las posiciones de los guiones que vienen luego de espacios... En caso de llgar al final agregamos *-1*. En caso de ser *-1*, luego se cortará hasta el final de la línea:

```
01234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789
0     6    12          24       33        43
0     6     2           4        3        -1
----  ----  ----------  -------  --------- -
```

El array de posiciones queda `[0,6,12,24,33,-1]`.

La cabecera de la tabla se agregará al final del array, mientras que todo lo demás, se agrega al principio. Esto se debe a que inicialmente no se sabe cuántas columnas tiene la tabla. La cantidad de columnas es conocida luego de analizar la línea de guiones.

Lo siguiente es la cabecera de la tabla:

```
Slot  Type     PEC      Primary  Secondary
```

Tanto la cabecera como las demás líneas, se cortarán en columnas mediante el array de posiciones, y se le quitarán los espacios de los costados.

```
|Slot|Type|PEC|Primary|Secondary|
```

Cada celda de la cabecera se le extraen palabras claves, y se las convierte a minúsculas. En caso de haber espacios, se lo une con guión bajo, adoptando la forma de *variables de la notación viborita*, como por ejemplo: `la_notacion_viborita`.

*Nota:* Esto es así solo para la cabecera, para las demás líneas no.

```
|slot|type|pec|primary|secondary|
```

Modo de uso de estas funciones (para analizar otras tablas, solo hay que intentar con otro *txt* que tenga la información):

```
my $salida = archivo_hacia_texto("tabla_texto.txt");
my @mi_matriz = obtener_matriz_campos($salida);
leer_matriz( @mi_matriz );
```

#### Código completo en *Perl*:

```
sub archivo_hacia_texto{
    my $nombre_archivo = shift;

    $ruta = $0;
    $ruta_actual = "";
    $caracteres_acumulados = "";
    for my $char (split //, $ruta) #/
    {
        $caracteres_acumulados = $caracteres_acumulados.$char;
        if( $char eq "/" ){
            $ruta_actual = $ruta_actual.$caracteres_acumulados;
            $caracteres_acumulados = "";
        }
    }
    $ruta_archivo = $ruta_actual . $nombre_archivo;
    open my $archivo, '<', $ruta_archivo;
    read $archivo, my $salida, -s $archivo;
    close $archivo;
    return $salida;
}
sub capturar_posiciones{
    my $linea = shift;
    my ( $posiciones_ref, $matriz_ref) = @_;

    my $posicion = 0;
    my $char_antiguo = "";
    for my $caracter (split //, $linea) #/
    {
        if( $caracter eq "-" && !($caracter eq $char_antiguo) ){
            push @$posiciones_ref, $posicion;
        }
        $char_antiguo = $caracter;
        ++$posicion;
    }
    push @$posiciones_ref, -1;
    my $cantidad_columnas = (scalar @$posiciones_ref)-2;
    push @$matriz_ref, $cantidad_columnas;
}

sub capturar_campos{
    my $linea = shift;
    my ( $posiciones_ref, $matriz_ref) = @_;
    my @posiciones = @{ $posiciones_ref };

    my @linea_caracteres = split(//, $linea); #/
    my $cantidad_columnas = (scalar @$posiciones_ref)-2;
    my $indice_columna = 0;
    while( $indice_columna < $cantidad_columnas ){
        my $inicio = @posiciones[ $indice_columna+1 ];
        my $fin = @posiciones[ $indice_columna+2 ]-1;
        if( $fin==-2 ){
            $fin = scalar @linea_caracteres;
        }
        my $capturado = join("", @linea_caracteres[$inicio..$fin] );
        $capturado =~ s/^[\s-]+|[\s-]+$//g; #/
        push @$matriz_ref, $capturado;

        ++$indice_columna;
    }
}

sub unificar_pendientes{
    my ( $matriz_ref, $pendientes_ref, $posiciones_ref ) = @_;

    my $cantidad_columnas = (scalar @$posiciones_ref)-2;
    my @pendientes_campos = [];

    my $indice_pendientes = 0;
    my $cantidad_pendientes = scalar @$pendientes_ref - 1;
    while( $indice_pendientes < $cantidad_pendientes ){
        my $linea = @$pendientes_ref[1+$indice_pendientes];
        capturar_campos( $linea, \@$posiciones_ref, \@pendientes_campos );
        ++$indice_pendientes;
    }
    my $indice_columna = 0;
    while( $indice_columna < $cantidad_columnas ){
        my $texto = "";
        $indice_pendientes = 0;
        while( $indice_pendientes < $cantidad_pendientes ){
            my $p = $cantidad_columnas * $indice_pendientes + $indice_columna+1;
            my $elemento = @pendientes_campos[ $p ];
            $texto = $texto . " " . $elemento;
            $texto =~ s/^[^a-zA-Z0-9]+|[^a-zA-Z0-9]+$//g; #/
            $texto =~ s/[^a-zA-Z0-9]+/\x20/g; #/
            my @texto_cortado = split /\s+/, $texto;  #/
            $texto = lc(join("_", @texto_cortado ));
            ++$indice_pendientes;
        }
        push @$matriz_ref, $texto;
        ++$indice_columna;
    }
}

sub obtener_matriz_campos
{
    my $texto = shift;

    my @posiciones = [];
    my @matriz = [];
    my @pendientes = [];

    for my $linea (split "\n", $texto)
    {
        my @linea_caracteres = split(//, $linea); #/
        my @guiones = ( $linea =~ /([-\s]+)/g );  #/

        my $cantidad_bloques_guiones = scalar @guiones;
        my $cantidad_columnas = @matriz[1];

        if( $cantidad_columnas > 0 ){
            capturar_campos( $linea, \@posiciones, \@matriz );
        }
        if( $cantidad_bloques_guiones == 1 && $cantidad_columnas == 0 ){
            capturar_posiciones( $linea, \@posiciones, \@matriz );
        }else{
            if( $cantidad_columnas == 0 ){
                push @pendientes, $linea;
            }
        }
    }
    unificar_pendientes(\@matriz, \@pendientes, \@posiciones );
    return @matriz;
}
sub leer_matriz{
    my @esta_matriz = @_;

    my $cantidad_columnas = @esta_matriz[1];
    my $cantidad_items = scalar @esta_matriz - 2;
    my $cantidad_filas = ($cantidad_items-1)/$cantidad_columnas - 1 ;
    my $indice_item = 0;
    print( $cantidad_items." ".$cantidad_filas." ".$cantidad_columnas."\n");
    while( $indice_item < $cantidad_items )
    {
        if( (($indice_item) % $cantidad_columnas)==0 ){
            print("\n|");
        }
        my $pos_item = -1;
        if( $indice_item < $cantidad_columnas ){
            $pos_item = $indice_item + $cantidad_items + 2 - $cantidad_columnas ;
        }else{
            $pos_item = $indice_item + 2 - $cantidad_columnas  ;
        }
        my $valor = @esta_matriz[ $pos_item ];
        print( $valor );
        print("|");
        ++$indice_item;
    }
    print("\n");
    return @esta_matriz;
}
my $salida = archivo_hacia_texto("tabla_texto.txt");
my @mi_matriz = obtener_matriz_campos($salida);
leer_matriz( @mi_matriz );
```

#### Resultado de la consola:

```
100 18.8 5

|slot|type|pec|primary|secondary|
|1|DMC||OOS Mtce|Unequipped|
|2|DMC|NTBN19CA|IS||
|3|DMC||NULL||
|4|DMC|NTBN19EA|IS||
|5|DMC|NTBN19CA|IS||
|6|DMC|NTBN19CA|IS||
|7|DMC|NTBN19CA|IS||
|8|DMC|NTBN19CA|IS||
|9|DMC|NTBN19CA|IS||
|10|DMC|NTBN19CA|IS||
|11|DMC|NTBN19CA|IS||
|12|DMC|NTBN19EA|IS||
|13|DMC|NTBN19CA|IS||
|14|DMC|NTBN19CA|IS||
|15|MSC|NTBN20BA|IS||
||SM|NTBN21AB|IS||
||SM|NULL|NULL||
||SM|NULL|NULL||
||SM|NULL|NULL||
```

Answer (score 1):

Sí, el problema de usar split() viene cuando los campos pueden estar vacíos y entonces se confunden con los espacios separadores de campos.

La solución, para este tipo de problemas, es usar los **---** que están debajo del **título** como guía para saber dónde empiezan y acaban los campos. Esas columnas las guardas en un array, y luego, por cada línea, vas extrayendo los campos con un simple substr().

Además, esa solución te servirá incluso si el formato de la salida cambia, tanto en el número de campos como en el ancho de cada columna.

Para extraer las posiciones de los guiones se puede usar una expresión regular en un bucle while(), y con la función pos(), o mejor, con el contenido de las variables **@-** y **@+**, te vale para saber la posición de cada columna.

Otra opción más potente es usar el comando unpack(). Aquí hay un ejemplo:
http://perlenespanol.com/foro/al-descargar-reemplazar-espacios-vacios-por-nan-t4470.html

Comment: Hola gracias por la respuesta.. Por favor me podrías ayudar con un ejemplo practico ya que el que me dejaste en el link no lo entiendo mucho gracias

Comment: Puedes entrar en el foro y plantear tu cuestión. Aquí en StackOverflow, es complicado poner código largo.